# Get a URL of the current page in Wicket for an OAuth redirect

Tags: wicket

I need to forward my user to an OAuth provider for login, and then pass a redirect URL to the OAuth provider. I'd like for the user to return to the same stateful page that they were currently on. In Apache Wicket (version 7), how can I generate a full URL that will take them back to the current page?

I'm looking for an external URL that will do the equivalent of:

```
add( new Link<Object>( "samePage") {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            setResponsePage( getPage() );
        }
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out - this approach generates a new render count, and works even from panels / components within the parent page:

```
String redirect = getRequestCycle().getUrlRenderer().renderFullUrl( Url.parse( getPage().urlFor( IRedirectListener.INTERFACE, new PageParameters() ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to obtain a full URL of the current page, but it's for 9.x, can't test 7.x:

```
Url currentUrl = ((WebRequest)RequestCycle.get().getRequest()).getUrl();
String fullUrl = RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer().renderFullUrl(currentUrl);
```

Comment: That doesn't increment the render count, so I get stale page exceptions when I try to use it. Also, in the process of turning it into a full URL, my path components get doubled up, like this (notice account is listed twice):

http://localhost:8080/FMCalDAV_war_exploded/admin/account/account/auth?12-1.ILinkListener-configwizard-form-view-samePage